# Attempting to enable web server logging on multiple on Azure web apps with quota and retention specified

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

Can someone please help me with my powershell script below?  The issue that I'm facing is the "ResourceName" flag is the name of the web app that is being configured, so I need to have an array for that and have the ForEach-Object loop run against that array.

```
$ResourceGroupName = 'webapptestrg'
$webapps = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName 'webapptestrg'
$ResourceName = foreach ($webapp in $webapps) {$webapp.name}

$PropertiesObject = @{
    httpLogs = @{
        fileSystem = @{
            enabled = $TRUE;
            retentionInMb = 35;
            retentionInDays = 7;
        }
    }
  }

Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName | ForEach-Object {
Set-AzResource -Properties $PropertiesObject `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config `
      -ResourceName $ResourceName.name/logs -ApiVersion 2018-11-01 -Force
      }
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the script work?

Comment: No, the script doesn't work.  The error returned is that the value for the -ResourceName flag in the Set-AzProperty cmdlet is null.  So, I know the issue is with defining the $ResourceName but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Update.  I had some help internally and we got it figured out.  For anyone that needs this in the future, here's the updated code.

```
$ResourceGroupName = 'rgname'
$webapps = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName 'rgname'
$ResourceName = foreach ($webapp in $webapps) {$webapp.name}
$PropertiesObject = @{
    httpLogs = @{
        fileSystem = @{
            enabled = $TRUE;
            retentionInMb = 35;
            retentionInDays = 7;
        }
    }
  }
      Foreach ($resource in $ResourceName) {
Set-AzResource -Properties $PropertiesObject `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config `
      -ResourceName "$resource/logs" -ApiVersion 2018-11-01 -Force
      }
```